# Inserior dados em um vetor para depois imprimir e multiplicar

Tags: c, array

> Escreva um algoritmo que leia dois vetores de 10 posições e faça a
>   multiplicação dos elementos de mesmo índice, colocando o resultado em
>   um terceiro vetor. Mostre o vetor resultante.

Queria primeiro mostrar os valores digitados para depois começar a elaborar o passo a passo da multiplicação. Seria assim que começaria?

```
int main(void) {

    int vetorA[10] = {0};
    int vetorB[10] = {0};

    int a,b;

    for(a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        printf("Vetor A: \n");
        a=getchar();


    for(b = 0; b < 10; b++){
        printf("Vetor B: \n");
        b=getchar();





        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual linguagem?

Comment: Linguagem c, grato se puder ajudar

Comment: 1º O modo como está obtendo os dados está errado [Wikipédia - Simple Input and Output](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_Input_and_Output) 2º Você pode mostrar os valores no mesmo `for` em que usar para somar os vetores `a` e `b` ( Depois você faz outro for para mostrar o valor da soma junto ao indice caso queira ) 3º Você deveria iniciar os contadores com 0 em suas intancias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem diversos erros nesse código, não está nem perto de fazer algo útil. Assim pelo menos começa certo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int vetorA[10] = { 0 };
    int vetorB[10] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Vetor A: \n");
        scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Vetor B: \n");
        scanf("%d", &vetorB[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R68PjH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/epgngggq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfOnArray.c).

Este é o começo certo, agora para imprimir é o mesmo algoritmo, só muda o `scanf()` para `printf()`. A multiplicação é feita da mesma forma que faz sem ser vetor, só que a variável sempre tem o índice `[]`, vai fazer outro *loop*, ou fazer junto com o *loop* de impressão.

Comment: para imprimir só os valores na tela por enquanto.. seria assim? int main(void) {
 
 int vetorA[10] = { 0 };
 int vetorB[10] = { 0 };
 
 int i;
 
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  printf("Vetor A: \n");
  scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);
  
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  printf("Vetor B: \n");
  scanf("%d", &vetorB[i]);
  
  } 
  
 }
 
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 
 printf("Vetor A: %d\n ",vetorA[i]);
 
 printf("Vetor B: %d\n ", vetorB[i]);
 
 }
 
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: Pode ser assim.

Comment: Porque preciso dar o espaço nessa parte(entre as chaves que estão o "0") : VetorA[10] = { 0 }

Comment: @RodrigoMuniz pra ficar mais legível.

Comment: "não está nem perto de fazer algo útil."  convenhamos - -esses exercícios artificias pra aprender C são ruins - esse aí não vai estar nem perto de fazer algo útil mesmo fucionando 100%.

Comment: @jsbueno ah, quase todos são assim, não tem muito jeito, mas pelo menos se sabe que todas essas pessoas nunca vão programar em C profissionalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Vc está inicializando seus vetores com apenas um valor {0} ao invés de ter 10 valores: {0,11,22,31,48,54,62,71,84,99}.

É melhor vc colocar o length do array ao invés de 10: `for(b = 0; b < vetorA.length; b++)`.

Para "mostrar" vc deve concatenar "Vetor B: \n" com vetorB[b], veja que o "b" entre colchetes é para indicar a posição do vetor, ou seja: `printf("Vetor B: \n" + vetor[b])`;

Para fazer a multiplicação vc faz um for para percorrer as posições dos dois vetores utilizando o "count" para indicar a posição dos vetores.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Valor multiplicado: \n" + (vetorA[i] * vetorB[i]);
}
```

Comment: Está inicializando com 0 em todos os elementos.

Answer (score 0):

para imprimir só os valores na tela por enquanto.. seria assim?

```
int main(void) {

    int vetorA[10] = { 0 };
    int vetorB[10] = { 0 };

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Vetor A: \n");
        scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Vetor B: \n");
        scanf("%d", &vetorB[i]);

        }   

    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    printf("Vetor A: %d\n ",vetorA[i]);

    printf("Vetor B: %d\n ", vetorB[i]);

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pergunta/feedback do OP na área de respostas

Source:

Você usou a área de respostas para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor incluir esse conteúdo na própria pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [edit], que fica logo abaixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em várias respostas e comentários para entender o problema.